# Ignore modules from Model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, api, activerecord

I have in my application a few controllers that i want to use as a api. In this api i need to use versioning.

in my `routes.rb` i`m using this:

```
require 'api_constraints'
```

(...)

```
  scope '/:target/:version', :module => :api, :constraints => { :version => /[0-z\.]+/ } , :defaults => { :format => 'json' } do
    scope :module => :v1, :constraints => ApiConstraints.new(:version => 1, :default => true) do
      match '/list' => 'sample#list'
    end
  end
```

my `api_constraints.rb`:

```
class ApiConstraints

  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/waytaxi.api.v#{@version}")
  end

  def self.version
    @version
  end

end
```

in my `SampleController.rb`:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SampleController < ApiBaseController

      def list
        render json: Model.find_by_id(params[:id])
      end

    end    
  end
end
```

the `ApiBaseController`:

```
module Api
  class ApiBaseController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  private

    def authenticate
      # if params[:target] == "ios"
      #   render :json => {status: 404}
      #   return false        
      # end
    end
  end  
end
```

the problem is:

whenever i try to call `Model` i get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Api::V1::SampleController::Model
```

If i use: `::Model` i get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Model
```

And yes, i do have this models on my database. If i use `Model.all` outside the `SampleController` i get the objects.

P.S.: I'm using rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem.

My Model was in plural and on my controller i was calling it in singular